# Making my HashTable implementation efficient with Linear Probing?

Tags: hash

I have to make a hashtable with openAddressing and use Linearprobing to resolve collisions.

I resize the array when it's about 40% full. The compression function compressing using   a simple % command so when I resize ( double the array) i also change the factor by which I mod the hashcodes in my compression function. This makes inserting a file with 100 000 strings pretty fast since it really avoids clustering. The problem is that the look up time now is very high because I can't go directly to the index by taking the hashcodes because not all entries were modded by the same mod factor ? i,e the first 1000 entries may have indices given as hashcode%1000 ,now when the array resized to 2000 the next entries' hashcodes come like hashcode%2000. I did this to avoid lots of linear probing and to make it more evenly spread.

So how can i make my search faster ?

Comment: "I resize the array when it's about 0.4% full." *Point* four percent? Is that correct? Or do you mean forty percent?

Comment: I mean I do this if (size == 0.4 * tableSize) ..Sorry , I meant 40%